# Is it possible that I could change the spreadsheet script to change use privilege?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My spreadsheet has several columns and I add a new custom menu into the tool bar.
There are several actions in that menu, for example, one is the add row function.
While a current problem is that some columns of the spreadsheet is protected. 
Say that the column A1 - A4 is protected and could only be edited by owner and admin. No I have my assistant and I did not grant him the privilege to edit A1-A4. Now I want him to use add row function, while because add a new row will generate a new row with A1-A4, but these columns are protected and he does not have that privilege. 
Thus I want to ask whether there is a method to change the privilege thru Google script. And my thinking is, when my assistants click "Add new row", the script will temporarily give him a high privilege and then after adding a new row, the privilege will go back, and in this case, he will be able to add a row, but after adding a row, he will not have the privilege anymore to edit A1-A4. There is only one assistant and I think maybe I could just point his email address to grant the privilege.
Could I please ask is there a possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this is a job primarily for scripts as you can go to Share option click on the user and change his roles to Editor (provided you're an Editor as well). With that the user will be able to make edits on the spreadsheet. If you go to [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection), you will see that you still need to check the roles before you can make edits.